# docker-compose .env file values with dollar: interpolated in MAC but not on Linux

Tags: linux, docker, macos, docker-compose, dollar-sign

test.yml

```yaml
version: "3.1"
services:
  test:
    container_name: test
    image: alpine
    environment:
      var: $test_variable
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c
    command: [ "echo $$var" ]
```

test.env

```yaml
test_variable=TE$T_VALUE3
```

command

```bash
docker-compose -f test.yml --env-file test.env up
```

---

**Output [Linux]**

```
Starting test ... done
Attaching to test
test    | TE$T_VALUE3
test exited with code 0
```

**Output [MacOS]**

```
WARN[0000] The “T_VALUE3” variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The “T_VALUE3" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The “T_VALUE3” variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
[+] Running 2/2
 :heavy_check_mark: test 1 layers [⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                                                                  3.4s
   :heavy_check_mark: c41833b44d91 Pull complete                                                                              0.8s
[+] Running 2/0
 :heavy_check_mark: Network test_default  Created                                                                             0.0s
 :heavy_check_mark: Container test        Created                                                                             0.0s
Attaching to test
test  | TE
test exited with code 0
```

Potentially related: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/10419

---

Why the inconsistency? It feels as if docker-compose on Mac was loading the .env file into the test.yml (the compose config) before processing it.

Is this a known issue? How to get around it and make cross-platform env files?

Quoting the value also works differently: on Linux the value is then loaded as-is, i.e. with quotes, and on Mac it's loaded w/o quotes, but also w/o the $ interpolation (i.e. the same way it's loaded on Linux w/o quotes). So quoting is also not an option for a cross-platform approach...

I couldn't find any references discussing this inconsistency, or `$` interpolation rules in .env files altogether.

---

**EDIT 1**

```
linux$ docker-compose -f test.yml --env-file test.env config
services:
  test:
    command:
    - echo $$var
    container_name: test
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c
    environment:
      var: TE$$$$T_VALUE3
    image: alpine
version: '3.1'
```

```
macos$ docker-compose -f test.yml --env-file test.env config
name: test
services:
  test:
    command:
    - echo $$var
    container_name: test
    entrypoint:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    environment:
      var: TE
    image: alpine
    networks:
      default: null
networks:
  default:
    name: test_default
```

**EDIT 2** [updated docker-compose on Linux to the latest version; same result]:

```
linux$ docker-compose --env-file test.env -f test.yml up
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container test  Recreated                                               0.0s 
Attaching to test
test  | TE$T_VALUE3
test exited with code 0
linux$
linux$ docker-compose --env-file test.env -f test.yml config
name: playground
services:
  test:
    command:
    - echo $$var
    container_name: test
    entrypoint:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    environment:
      var: TE$$T_VALUE3
    image: alpine
    networks:
      default: null
networks:
  default:
    name: playground_default
linux$
linux$ docker-compose --version
Docker Compose version v2.17.2
```

At least quoting the value now no longer treats quotes as part of the value:

```
linux$ docker-compose --env-file test.env -f test.yml up
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container test  Recreated                                               0.0s 
Attaching to test
test  | TE$T_VALUE3
test exited with code 0
linux$
linux$ cat test.env 
test_variable='TE$T_VALUE3'
```

MacOS docker-compose version:

```
Docker Compose version 2.17.0
```

Still, the inconsistency of interpolating $ in unquoted values remains

Comment: What is 'docker-compose -f test.yml --env-file test.env config' output?

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu Updated OP with the outputs

Answer (score 1):

To prevent interpolation on dot.env file values, you have to wrap those with single quotes:

```
$ cat .env 
KEY='$2a$10$bY3ZpvQN/nTFHFSZjaZg1On50ueeibFctofVzk4uQu8gXPdkkyVZO'
$ cat compose.yaml 
services:
  foo:
    image: alpine
    env_file:
      - .env
$ docker compose run foo | grep KEY
KEY=$2a$10$bY3ZpvQN/nTFHFSZjaZg1On50ueeibFctofVzk4uQu8gXPdkkyVZO
```

> Why the inconsistency?

based on output format, your Linux installation runs Docker Compose v1 (soon to be EoL)

Comment: Thank you. See EDIT 2 in OP. Updated docker-compose to the latest available, now quoted values are treated the same. Still, the inconsistency of unquoted values remains

Comment: If you updated your answer with the details about v1/v2 of docker-compose I could mark it as accepted